# Writing (updating) string to IsolatedStorage does not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

When the application is started an update check for a textfile is performed. If the version number of the remote file is higher than the local one, the remote file shall be saved to isolated storage and replace the current one. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. There's still the old file in the storage.

```
    public static bool WriteFileToIsolatedStorage(String content, String fileName)
    {
        bool result = false;

        MessageBox.Show(Leser.GetVersionInfo(content));

        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate, store));

        try
        {
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I tried several FileMode parameters like "Create" or "Truncate", but when the application is restarted, there is always an update available. There is no error while writing to the storage but the version number indicates that it didn't work properly.

I have a text file in my project explorer with the data that should be updated as described above. At the beginning I check the storage for this file and if not found, it will be written to it. This works as expected. But the updated version is not written and I don't have a clue why not.

SOLUTION: Writing works fine :) The problem was that I read the ressource file and not the file saved to IsolatedStorage

```
    public static String ReadFileContents(String file)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        var ResourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
        if (ResourceStream != null)
        {
            Stream myFileStream = ResourceStream.Stream;
            if (myFileStream.CanRead)
            {
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);
                content = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return content;
    }
```

Sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I used to create a file and replace it .... Just changing the keyword `Truncate to Create` will help you.

```
public static bool WriteFileToIsolatedStorage(String content, String fileName)
    {
        bool result = false;

        //MessageBox.Show(Leser.GetVersionInfo(content));

        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, store));

        try
        {
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, store));
        string rawData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();


        return result;
    }
```

I used stream reader just to verify that it is getting replaced :)

Comment: As mentioned above I tried the "Create" parameter already and as I noticed the error was within another function, but thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, but try this:

```
    public static bool WriteFileToIsolatedStorage(String content, String fileName)
    {
        bool result = false;

        MessageBox.Show(Leser.GetVersionInfo(content));
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate, store))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(content);

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Not only is it a good idea to dispose of anything you instantiate it should also ensure that everything is flushed and closed (even though this probably happens implicitly in the StreamWriter so this is a bit of a shot in the dark)

Comment: Didn't help but I'm gonna use the using-clause in the future thx ;)